# The intent is on null in service when getting data from receiver

Tags: android, android-studio

I have develop simple app for phone state listner for that I am starting service when call is in `incoming mode` and `idle mode` it is working fine but I want to pass data from `broadcast receiver` to my `service` I am starting my service from `broadcast` like this

```
Intent reivToServ = new Intent(context, RecorderService.class);
reivToServ.putExtra("number",phoneNumber);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
{
    context.startForegroundService(reivToServ);
}
else 
{
    reivToServ.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
    context.startService(reivToServ);
}
```

and for getting the data inside service

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    
        Log.i("command",intent.getStringExtra("number"));
    }
```

But the intent is on null please any solution for this

Comment: Did you register the broadcast receiver in manifest? Also, how do you start your Brodacast receiver?  There might be a case that the receiver is not started.

Comment: yes i have registered broadcast receiver in manifest

Comment: Put a log.d in your receiver to test if it’s strated.

Comment: Receiver is started well and also able to start service but problem is only the data is not passing from receiver to service

Comment: But why the data is not sharing from broadcast to service

Comment: I think the intent will not pass between `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657302/passing-data-from-broadcastreceiver-to-service Check it out

Comment: I have use also `bundle` but this also not working `bundle.putString("number",phoneNumber);`
`i.putExtras(bundle);` and starting forground and in `onstartCommand` i have added this `Bundle  bundle =intent.getExtras();` but `bundle.getString("number")` is on null